# I need my FB dev account to point to an IP and not domain

Tags: facebook, dns

I created my Facebook developer account and got my app id, secret etc.  My app domain is mypersonaldoman.com (not real) and my website is http://www.mypersonaldoman.com/.  I created a test page there to display the Facebook Log In button and log a user in and display their info and friend list.  It all works fine.

The problem is that now I go to my dev environment at work and want to use my same id/secret for testing but Facebook won't let me log in.  I get the following error:

> API Error Code: 191
> API Error Description:  The specified URL is not owned by the application
> Error Message: Invalid redirect_url: Given URL is not allowed by the application configuration.

This is what I get when I'm already logged in to Facebook.  When I'm not I just get:

> "An error occurred with Murphy Dev.  Please try again later."

At work I just have a dev box with no domain name, just an IP.  How can I set this up to point to my dev box (just the IP)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should create different apps for different environments and store their respective app ID and secret in a web config.  Each different app on facebook then points to the

I have about 11 unique apps, and each of those apps has 3 different app ids.  One for my localhost, one for the test environment and one for prod. Yes, I have 33 apps in total.

This is how I name them

- MyAwesomeApp [local]
- MyAwesomeApp [test]
- MyAwesomeApp

Notice I don't use [prod] on it since real people/users will see that name.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response.  In my original app creation I entered that hostname and it wouldn't let me change it to an IP address so I assumed that a new app wouldn't let me enter an IP either.

Comment: Please consider clicking the green checkmark if this response was the answer to your question! = ) It gives @DMCS some points as a reward for his efforts.